# Set UIImageView image using a url

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Is it possible to read a url to an image and set a UIImageView to the image at this url?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's possible to load an NSData from a URL and convert that to an image and stick that in the image view, but this is an extremely bad idea because it involves doing a synchronous URL download on the main thread. This will lock up the UI and possibly cause the user to think your app has crashed if the image doesn't download extremely fast.

**Edit**: To clarify, the original question looks to me like the poster wants to say something along the lines of

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
```

Hence my answer. It's possible to do the equivalent by going through NSData, but it's a bad idea. Instead, the image should be downloaded asynchronously using NSURLConnection, and only once it's fully downloaded should it be converted into a UIImage and assigned to the image view.

Comment: +1 As you say, it's definitely a bad idea. That said, you could use a placeholder image and then fire off an NSURLConnection in the background.

Comment: Ok. what about multi threading? Are there any other ways to design a dynamic app which, my idea is to read in a plist, and use the links within this list to e.g. read an image and display it. I dont want to have to update the app every time the site updates.

Comment: @alJaree As I've suggested you could use a placeholder image and load the "current" image asynchronously via an NSURLConnection. There's a good example of how to use an NSURLConnection within the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

Comment: you should also consider caching the image(s) that you download so you first check if you have it in already before firing the download (thinking the image itself won't change from the one in the server)

Comment: Thanks for the edited question. So do one of these connections needed to be started for each image?

Comment: @alJaree If you're talking about an NSURLConnection, then yes. Each connection simply downloads data a bit at at time from a single source.

Comment: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:theURL]; method doesn't available now.

Comment: are there any good libs that go about doing this, I am using Picasso for Android which does wonders making it simple by just taking in the url and then it is placed into the view and also handles caching... anyone?

Answer (score 60):

For such a straightforward task I would highly recommend against integrating projects such as Three20, the library is a monster and not very straightforward to get up and running.

I would instead recommend this approach:

```
NSString *imageUrl = @"http://www.foo.com/myImage.jpg";
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    myImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}];
```

## EDIT for Swift 3.0

```
let urlString = "http://www.foo.com/myImage.jpg"
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed fetching image:", error)
        return
    }

    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
        print("Not a proper HTTPURLResponse or statusCode")
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    }
}.resume()
```

*EDIT for Swift 2.0

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)

NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to load image for url: \(urlString), error: \(error?.description)")
        return
    }

    guard let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse else {
        print("Not an NSHTTPURLResponse from loading url: \(urlString)")
        return
    }

    if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
        print("Bad response statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode) while loading url: \(urlString)")
        return
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    })

    }.resume()
```

Comment: `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` is deprecated in iOS 9, now use `[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]`

Comment: Awesome answer works great thanks.  The only thing I would say is to ```guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString) else {return}``` and then ```let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)``` just on the off chance that the url string is malformed to avoid crashing.

Answer (score 57):

```
NSString *ImageURL = @"YourURLHere";
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: This is synchronous and will lock up the main thread while the image is retrieved.  A really bad idea.

Comment: Use HJCache (can be found in github) if u have a long data. avoid UI freeze up.

Comment: You could easily make it asynchronous. But it's essence is the most elegant.

Comment: It is up to the developer to decide whether synchronous access is good enough or not - and furthermore, the creation of the UIImage and synchronous loading of a remote file from URL - can be of course wrapped in a dispatch_async, NSOperation, background-thread or any other technique for concurrency, caching or whatever. The only thing you must do on the main thread is attaching the image to the imageView. So the answer is perfectly viable and correct, and has no direct performance implications

Answer (score 24):

I am using https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage which is a beautifully designed library, which has the options to put a placeholder image, whether to memory, or disk cache the image or use the downloader independent of a `UIImageView`.

I was trying to do that by myself but the library took all the pain away.

All you need to do is to write the code below for your case :

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: I always prefer to write my own code, but for just 5 minutes of work, the smoothness and speed I got from this library is just impressive. The detailed install explanation helped too.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to display image from Url in ImageView, And also want to save this image in cache for optimize to server interaction this would help you Just pass your imageView object and string Url to this function

```
-(void)downloadingServerImageFromUrl:(UIImageView*)imgView AndUrl:(NSString*)strUrl{


strUrl = [strUrl encodeUrl];

NSString* theFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[[strUrl lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];


NSFileManager *fileManager =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *fileName = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tmp/%@",theFileName]];



imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
UIActivityIndicatorView *actView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[imgView addSubview:actView];
[actView startAnimating];
CGSize boundsSize = imgView.bounds.size;
CGRect frameToCenter = actView.frame;
// center horizontally
if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
    frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
else
    frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;

// center vertically
if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
    frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
else
    frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;

actView.frame = frameToCenter;


dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSData *dataFromFile = nil;
    NSData *dataFromUrl = nil;

    dataFromFile = [fileManager contentsAtPath:fileName];
    if(dataFromFile==nil){
        dataFromUrl=[[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]] autorelease];                      
    }

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if(dataFromFile!=nil){
            imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataFromFile];
        }else if(dataFromUrl!=nil){
            imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataFromUrl];  
            NSString *fileName = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tmp/%@",theFileName]];

            BOOL filecreationSuccess = [fileManager createFileAtPath:fileName contents:dataFromUrl attributes:nil];       
            if(filecreationSuccess == NO){
                NSLog(@"Failed to create the html file");
            }

        }else{
            imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NO_Image.png"];  
        }
        [actView removeFromSuperview];
        [actView release];
        [imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    });
});


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an updated answer to the best answer, as imageWithContentsOfURL is no longer a method of UIImage. You'll have to use CIImage:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url_goes_here.com/logo.png"];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Comment: This I liked the most, although I'd break into 3 lines, to allow deferring the creation of the CIImage (and synchronous loading of remote file from URL) to some background task.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this feature is not available as of this writing... instead you will have to implement the functionality yourself by:

1. Downloading the data of the image
2. Saving it or caching it somewhere (db or filesystem) and then
3. Setting the UIImaveView to the saved structure

Fortunately you don't have to break your head coming out with said functionality as Apple provides [an example that does exactly that](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) as part of their code samples.

Follow the code and I'm sure you will be able to accommodate it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. It mentions rss. doesnt this example just read in an rss stream and grab the images? I already have this functionality in the app, I am now trying to read in a data structure from the a url of the site. Use this structure in my app to get the amount of images, and then take the url for each image and depending on its corresponding number in the plist, set a particular UIImageView with the image, this way I can dynamically update the app and replace the images.

Comment: that's just part of the functionality of the sample app but where you want to put ur attention is the part where it takes the url of the images and fetches them (that's what the IconDownloader class is for)... this sample goes one extra step as it also shows you how to use this class from a tableview in a way that is efficient.

Answer (score 2):

[EGOImageLoading](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading)

```
EGOImageView* imageView = [[EGOImageView alloc] initWithPlaceholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 36.0f, 36.0f);

//show the placeholder image instantly
[self.anyView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release] //if you want

//load the image from url asynchronously with caching automagically
imageView.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:photoURL];
```

If you want more, there is a delegate to handle actions after loading

```
@protocol EGOImageViewDelegate<NSObject>
@optional
- (void)imageViewLoadedImage:(EGOImageView*)imageView;
- (void)imageViewFailedToLoadImage:(EGOImageView*)imageView error:(NSError*)error;
@end
```

Comment: what's the point? UIImageView supports place-holder images natively?

Comment: @MottiShneor Please show the code on how does the `UIImageView` support it then?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is TTImageView from the Three20 library which handles asynchronous loading of an image. The control works great. However, the downside is you have to deal with the nightmare of installing Three20 (which is then almost impossible to fully remove).

Answer (score 1):

use `AFNetworking` category `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`

```
 #import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h


[profileImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```