# imageWithContentsOfURL Check if image is valid

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I am using the following code to obtain an image from a URL and display it in a `UIImageView`

How can I check that the URL I am passing has returned a valid image? (i.e the image exists?)

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringurl];
myimage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it is answered in: [UIImageview-image-using-a-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962561/set-uiimageview-image-using-a-url)

If that is not sufficient take a look at the nice asynchronous capabilities offered by [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com).