# How to pass an url image to button in ios with out doing NSData conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uiimage

I wants to display a imageurl on button from the server.In the server i have image url's.
I wants to do user interactions so i am use a button.

I have done below:

1. Retrieve the image url from server.
2. Convert > NSData to ImageObject
3. Added the imageObject to setImageProperty then it's sucessfully displaying the image but the performance was slowly.

but I don't want to use `NSData` operations. Because it's take so much time.I wants to show the good performance in the app.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: So your problem is that the image download takes too long?

Comment: Its not the problem with NSData operation, it seems your image retrieval will take time because its coming from server so it depends on internet speed.

Comment: Try to use SDWebImage from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I have used SDWebImage have the property to use imageview not for button right. 
the property is `sd_SetImageWithUrl`

Comment: @Jyoshna check my answer. it has property `sd_setImageWithURL: forState` and `sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:forState` . for that you have to add `#import "UIButton+WebCache.h"`

Comment: Okay thank you, can you please provide the SDWebImage library for non-arc.

Comment: @Jyoshna i can not provide that coz i'm not author of that library :). you should use latest coz of bug fixes.

Comment: It's ok, Actually, i need non-arc because.. i have developed this project in xcode 4.3. so it wont support arc files.

Comment: @Jyoshna non-arc project can support arc files. arc project can not support non-arc file. have you try to integrate?

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani yeah i have integrated am getting some architecture missing errors i386.
like` Apple Mach-O linker Error
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex", referenced from:` like this.. so many errors

Comment: @Jyoshna have you follow all steps to integrate? Read all steps on that link. you have to add few framework and linkerflag.

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani yes.. i have added ImageIO library and other linker flags also.. but still same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another easy solution would be to use `AFNetworking`'s `UIButton` category to set the image.

[`-(void)setImageForState:withURL:`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIButton%2BAFNetworking.h#L79)

This method will handle all the nitty gritty of downloading and converting the image. Your UI will not block because it is an async process. This will give your users a better overall experience.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library. its good library with caching functionality.

Just integrate below code.

add below code in `appDidFinishLauching` because using lifo execution last image will be download first

```
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager.imageDownloader.executionOrder = SDWebImageDownloaderLIFOExecutionOrder;
```

then import class in your viewcontroller.

```
#import "UIButton+WebCache.h"
```

and for integration

```
//set button image
[btn sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your string"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//set background image
[btn sd_setBackgroundImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your string"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

you can also download image in background thread using below code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your string with encoding"];
    if (data)
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (img)
               [btn setImage:btn forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        });
    }
});
```

*But I presonally prefer SDWebImage library because it is good library and it will handle cache so you dont want to cache image.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use dispatch queue.Here also converting NSString image URL to NSDATA, but it will work fast.

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
            NSString *ImageURL = @"yourURL.jpg";
            NSData *imageData;
            if (ImageURL == nil || ImageURL == (id)[NSNull null] || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ImageURL] length] == 0 || [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ImageURL] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0)
            {
            }

            else
            {
                imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];

            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if (ImageURL == nil || ImageURL == (id)[NSNull null] || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ImageURL] length] == 0 || [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ImageURL] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0)
                {
                    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo_frame_noimage.png"];
                }
                else if (imageData == nil || imageData == (id)[NSNull null] || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageData] length] == 0 || [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageData] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0)
                {
                    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo_frame_noimage.png"];
                }
                else
                {
                    imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: What I think is that we have to create a custom button to which we have to pass this URL and it is the responsibility of the button to download the image and set to itself.

Comment: @Nikita Khandelwal : This will not resolve time issue. Button will still take the same amount of time to get loaded with downloaded imagedata.

Comment: Here actually image is taking time to download the data.So dispatch queue will perform this function fastly.

Comment: GCD is used for asynchronous task only, here until you get image downloaded there is no way to set it to UIButton. And here each time it requires to update UI on main thread so, it is not gonna affect much in this scenario. Obviously if there is a large bunch of data then GCD is the only way.

Comment: The main purpose is to download the image in background and make the UI responsive to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether it will resolve your loading time or not, but this will surely reduce application running cycle.

```
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:theURL]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Similar Question: [Set UIImageView image using a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962561/set-uiimageview-image-using-a-url)

Hope this helps.

Comment: As per your statement, i am getting an error. imageWithContentsOfURL
`+Class method imageWithContentsOfURL not found (id)`

Comment: @Jyoshna Updated ans, sorry for mistaking at first go.